# Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with discrete topology. Show that only dense subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology

When answering general topology questions which ask to show a statement is true, I struggle to be able to formulate a sufficient proof, linking the information I know together. As the title is put, this particular question asks me to 'show that the only dense subset of  $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$' and to consider '$\mathbb{Z}$ with discrete topology' as additional information to the question. Below I have provided how I answered the question:

My attempt:

All subsets are closed and open in the discrete topology.

A $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}$ if ${\overline A}$ = $\mathbb{Z}$.

Evidently $\mathbb{Z}$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}$ since $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ = $\mathbb{Z}$.

Any B  $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{Z}$ will not be dense in $\mathbb{Z}$ since for all other B $\subset$ $\mathbb{Z}$ there exists a x in $\mathbb{Z}$ \ B which stops $\overline{B}$ = $\mathbb{Z}$.

In this solution, I dont think it is a strong enough proof and I do not know how to apply the fact that all subsets are closed and open. If anyone can tell me where I am going wrong or how to improve, it is appreciated.

Comment: From [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): **Your question should be clear without the title** After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: @jjagmath Okay, I will edit the question using this advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is incomplete, because it is false that the existence of a $x\in\Bbb Z\setminus B$ is incompatible with the fact that $B$ is dense. It is true in your case, but you did not explain why. But, for instance, $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ (with respect to the usual distance), in spite of the fact that $\sqrt2\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

If $B$ is dense, then $\overline B=\Bbb Z$. But $B$ is closed, and therefore $\Bbb Z=\overline B=B$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Indeed. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I do not understand how to explain why; I thought it was clear from the definition of a closure of a subset? To be clear, I thought that if there does exist an x satisfying that condition then then the closure of B (in this case) cannot equal $\mathbb{Z}$ - the open set U containing that particular x intersecting with B would give an empty set so technically the closure of B would be $\mathbb{Z}$ \ x?

Comment: @user962766 It is not true that $\overline B$ is always equal to $\Bbb Z\setminus\{x\}$ (not that $\Bbb Z\setminus x$ makes no sense). For instance, if $B=\Bbb Z\setminus\{0,1\}$ and if $x=0$, then $\overline B=B\ne\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. But you can say that $\overline B\subset\overline{\Bbb Z\setminus\{x\}}=\Bbb Z\setminus\{x\}$, and that therefore $\overline B\ne\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Ah yes, the first two sentences made perfect sense to me thank you. But I do not understand your last sentence?

Comment: Also, and I think its lack of knowledge on my behalf, why does B being closed mean that the integer set equals B and the closure of B?

Comment: My last sentence contains a proof of the fact that, if there is some $x\in\Bbb Z\setminus B$, then $\overline B\ne\Bbb Z$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes that is very clear thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ dense in $\Bbb Z$, then $\Bbb Z =\bar A = A$